# Will GRUB work across multiple physical drives?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, grub

I am presently intending to take a computer which has, besides `/dev/sda\d` partitions, a `/dev/sdb\d` removable drive.

I would like to install Windows on the main drive, and then Mint on the removable drive, **and** have GRUB offer the user's choice of operating system on boot.

Is it possible to have GRUB tell the computer, when it boots on the internal hard drive, to offer a choice between booting off the two disks?

If it is possible, how straightforward (or not) is it? If there are more steps or difficulties, what else needs to be done besides what you would run to register multiple bootable partitions on one single disk?

Thanks,

Comment: Grub can be installed as the bootloader on multiple disks; this must be done when booting from a RAID.  I'm pretty sure besides that you just need to have your hardware then boot from the external drive when required; it will for sure boot from the internal drive.  If you designate drives based on UUID, then it should be drive "position" agnostic.

Comment: Thanks! Please restate your comment as an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Grub can be installed as the bootloader on multiple disks; this must be done when booting from a RAID.

I'm pretty sure besides that you just need to have your hardware (motherboard) then boot from the external drive when required.  Weather or not you can boot from the external drive should be hardware dependant with most hadrware allowing it.  Every motherboard has a different way to select which device to boot from and what devices are "bootable".  It will for sure boot from the internal drive.

Then, in the grub configuration files, if you designate drives/partitions based on UUID, the drives should be drive "position" agnostic which is critical to grub finding the proper partitions to boot from when things are moved around.

Grub can be touchy at times, but typically if you are using UUIDs and have run through the commands properly things usually run pretty seamlessly; however sometimes I manually verify things match up in grub.cfg to ensure a smooth boot process before rebooting after messing with the grub configuration.